# How do you define a block of executable memory in windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, memory-management, window

I know that Linux supports the `mmap` system command for being able to define a block of executable memory. How do you do the same thing in windows? I imagine there is some windows equivalent function that does the same thing, maybe?

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx) or [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898.aspx) or [`VirtualAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887.aspx) passing one of the [`PAGE_EXECUTE_XXX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786.aspx) protection flags. The `mmap` function is used for file mappings and so `CreateFileMapping` is the closest Windows analogue.

Answer (score 4):

[Google, one of the first hits.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - use the `VirtualAlloc` function with the protection flag being one of `PAGE_EXECUTE`, `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`, `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`, or `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY`.

Alternatively, use [`VirtualProtect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the protection of an already existing memory region.