# Executing on stack in GDB?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, stack

I'm working on a binary-based Capture The Flag exercise, the first one in a series. I had the idea of writing code to the stack and executing it. To test this out, I ran the executable with a special input, so that it would jump to the code in the stack. To test this, I used `gdb`, and it worked!

However, when I tried to run this outside of `gdb`, I received the dreaded `Segmentation Fault`. I *think* this is because Ubuntu 16.04 does not allow code to be executed on the stack, but I'm not sure.

If this is the case, how come I could execute in `gdb`?

Also also, I tried using `execstack -s` on the exercise binary, it didn't do anything, so I'm starting to suspect that I may be having different issues. But, if I'm having different issues, how do I debug those issues without resorting to `gdb`, wherein the process works perfectly?

Comment: On linux, I believe you are looking for the mmap function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16677410/2189500)).

Comment: If you show us your shell exploit assembly code it would help. If it works in the debugger and not outside it could be that your code relies on a register being initialized to zero which may not be guaranteed.

Comment: Also, gdb turns off ASLR.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It does not depend on zero'd register settings, the registers are in a well-defined position when it jumps to stack. I'm reluctant to share the code, since this is a (potential) solution for the pwnable.tw "start" challenge, and I don't want to be a spoilsport.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick This program was built to be exploitable, it has `Entry point address: 0x8048060` in the ELF. Then again, that only happens for the text segment. Is there ASLR for the stack? I've only heard of it for dynamic/static libraries to prevent things like "return-to-libc" attacks.

Comment: @LarryB. Indeed there is. Try running `main() { int i; printf("%p\n", &i); }`  a few times. (My Ubuntu 16.04 comes with kernel 4.4.0).

Comment: @LarryB.: PIE executables have ASLR for the text / data / bss segments of the main executable, using the same mechanism as dynamic libraries (ELF shared objects).  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more.

Comment: Thank you @MarkPlotnick, that program did change the stack pointer. You helped me figure out the puzzle. If you want to come and collect your fake internet points, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mark Plotnick for helping me with this answer!

It turns out that I could execute from stack, in GDB and outside GDB. The issue was, indeed, ASLR. I finagled the stack pointer's "actual value" so that the program would "return to stack" where I injected the program. This is as opposed to writing the stack pointer's memory address as an immediate, which worked in GDB, but wouldn't work outside it because, as Mark Plotnick says, "GDB turns off ASLR" which randomizes the stack pointer's base address.